# Wordpress i18n embed variable string to translated string

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I'm writing a custom plugin that needs i18n ready, so there's this array in which I have some string I want to translate:

```
array(
    'description' => __('Recommended image width is %s and height is %s', get_option('my_image_width'), get_option('my_image_height'), 'my_domain')
);
```

And it seems the value of `my_image_width` and `my_image_height` is not embeding into the text nor replacing the `%s`, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Weill I just figured out, use the sprintf function:

```
array(
    'description'   =>  sprintf( __('Recommended image width is %s and height is %s', 'my_domain'), get_option('my_image_width'), get_option('my_image_height') ) 
);
```